# Using returning on insert in laravel and postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert values into postgresql 10 with Laravel 5.6. I have a table like this:

```
test
----
test_id     (identity generated by default, primary key)
test_name
```

My problem is getting the `test_id` that was just inserted back.

```
$test_id = \DB::connection('pgsql')->insert(
    'INSERT INTO test (test_name) VALUES (?) RETURNING test_id', 
    ['hello world']
);
```

If I print out `$test_id`, it just prints `1`. I'm doing this over a loop, with different names. Everything inserts correctly, but even if `test_id` is `6` in the database, I keep getting back `1`.

How can I correctly return `$test_id` in Laravel?

Comment: Can you try $test_id->test_id

Comment: @berkaykılıç I get an error: `Trying to get property 'test_id' of non-object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use `insertGetId`, eg:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    [ 'name' => 'first' ]
);
```

or try this:

```
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

In your case this worked:

```
$id = DB::connection('pgsql')
    ->table('test')
    ->insertGetId(['test_name' => 'hello world'], 'test_id');
```

https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-get-last-inserted-id-with-example

Comment: Using `insertGetId` gives me the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection::insertGetId()`. Any idea why?

Comment: ah, guess method doesnt belong to post gres connection but to the query builder. updated answer, maybe u can see a way to use it.

Comment: I'm using multiple types of databases so `DB::table` wouldn't work. I did figure it out based on the `table` method. If you want to update your answer I can accept it, otherwise I'll post my own. The final query looks like: `$test_id = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('test')->insertGetId(['test_name' => 'hello world'], 'test_id');` I guess as a second parameter you can specify what you want it to return.

Answer (score 1):

kind of old but I've just solved this issue in a funny way and wanted to share my answer.

It's kind of weird but the use of select and selectOne laravel function is the key:

```php
// Single row insertion
$insertion = DB::selectOne("INSERT INTO cities (user_uuid, postal_code) VALUES (?, ?) RETURNING uuid", [$name, $postal_code]);

echo $insertion->uuid;


// Multiple rows insertion
$insertion = DB::select("INSERT INTO cities (user_uuid, postal_code) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?) RETURNING uuid", [$name, $postal_code, $name, $postal_code]);

foreach($insertion as $city) {
    echo $city->uuid;
}
```

Have fun :)